# Can Anyone explained the like char - 'a'

Tags: c++, char

```
struct Node{
    bool isTerminal_;
    char ch_;
    Node* children_[26];
    Node(char c='\0'){
        isTerminal_ = false;
        ch_=c;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 26; i++){
            children_[i]=nullptr;
        }
    }

    //given a lower case alphabetic character ch, returns the associated index 'a'-> 0, 'b'->1....
    int getIndex(char c){
        if(c=='\0'){
            return 0;
        }
        return c -'a';
    }
};
```

found this code but i dont understand how does the "return c-'a';" works. It should be giving the index of a letter but how does char - char works?

Comment: A look to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) will help you to understand. If `c = 'z'`, you have `'z' (122) - 'a' (97) = 25`

Comment: `char` is just another kind of integer. So char - char is simply integer subtraction.

Comment: Ok, thank you :) the link helped a lot

Comment: `char` is a numeric type. The code is assuming that `c` represents an alphabetic letter between `a..z` inclusive. In ASCII, letters are consecutive, where `a` is 97, `b` is 98, etc, so subtracting `'a'` from `ch='a'` returns 0, subtracting `'a'` from `ch='b'` returns 1, and so on.

Comment: It is curios that commenters and people posted answers readily assumed ASCII encoding. Nothing in the question ensures it. Please note, there are more than one encoding out there, notably, there is an EBDIC encoding. And C++ is not married to ASCII.

Comment: @SergeyA -- Yep.  `const char *alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; return strchr(alph, c) - alph;` -- is a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I do not see anything particularly dirty about it (I'd use `constexpr const char*` for good measure, but that's mostly a matter of choice)

Answer (score 0):

A char can be represented as an ASCII number.

Here's a reference to the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

So let's suppose c = 'b', in the table 'b' equals to 98, and 'a' equals to 97, so 98 - 97 = 1.

Comment: The C++ standard does not require that compiled programs use ASCII. There are other character encodings for which this code will not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Every character have an integer value where you can find in ASCII table. Capital 'A' has value 65 and for capital 'B' it is 66('A'+1), so by doing ch-'a' you will get the index of the character(ex: ch='b' ch-'a'=1)

Comment: The C++ standard does not require that compiled programs use ASCII. There are other character encodings for which this code will not work correctly.